# getting minimum and maximum value in List[Option[Int or Long or Float]]

Tags: scala

I'm trying to get the minimum and maximum values in a list of ordered numbers.
There is no problem when working with specific type:

```
private def minMaxValue (valuesList: List[Option[Int]], min: Boolean): Option[Int] = 
  valuesList.flatten match {
  case Nil => None
  case xs => Some(if (min) xs.min else xs.max)
}
```

but when I can't find the way to change it to also accept Long and Float, I tried:

```
private def minMaxValue (valuesList: List[Option[Any]], min: Boolean): Option[Int] = 
  valuesList.flatten match {
  case Nil => None
  case xs: List[Int] => Some(if (min) xs.min else xs.max)
  case xs: List[Long] => Some(if (min) xs.min else xs.max)
}
```

but it doesn't work and I get this warning for

> - non-variable type argument Int in type pattern List[Int] (the underlying of List[Int]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by 
>      erasure

What is the best way to solve this in scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
def minMaxValue[T <% Ordered[T]](valuesList: List[Option[T]], min: Boolean): Option[T] = 
  valuesList.flatten match {
    case Nil => None
    case xs => Some(if (min) xs.min else xs.max)
  }
```

This creates a generic function with a type parameter `T`. You have to declare that `T` is an ordered type, so the compiler can prove that a collection of `T`s has `min` and `max` methods.

It works well for ints and doubles:

```
scala> minMaxValue(List(Option(1), None, Option(3)), false)
res7: Option[Int] = Some(3)

scala> minMaxValue(List(Option(1.0), None, Option(3.0)), false)
res8: Option[Double] = Some(3.0)

scala> minMaxValue(List(Option(1.0), None, Option(3.0)), true)
res9: Option[Double] = Some(1.0)
```

The thing with type erasure in the JVM is that type parameters are available only at compile time but not at runtime. In my solution, the compiler sees the type `T` and can use that information for type checking and for generating a function that works for the specific value of `T` that you are using. In your code, you need to tell if something is a `List[Int]` or a `List[Long]` at runtime, but that information is already erased by then.

Comment: Mind that view bounds are deprecated, you should use context bounds, and it's more general to use `Ordering` instead of `Ordered`: `def minMaxValue[T : Ordering]`

Comment: @Kolmar, in fact, it's not correct to say "you should use context bounds instead of view bounds" - after all, context bounds are not a direct replacement of view bounds. The correct approach would be to expand view bounds as implicit function arguments (adding `(implicit ev: T => Ordered[T])` for this case, for example). That said, I do agree that context bounds in particular and the type class pattern in general are better in most cases.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev But it's not a problem to define a direct replacement of view bounds with context bounds in any concrete case: http://jatinpuri.com/2014/03/replace-view-bounds/ And in general you can define `trait As[M] { type View[T] = T => M }`, and then instead of `def foo[T <% Int]` you have `def foo[T : As[Int]#View]`. It's only a little more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

I would transform the `List[Option[Int]]` to a `List[Int]` to be able to use the `max` and `min` methods.

```
val listOpt = List(Some(3), None, Some(7))

val listValues = listOpt.collect{
  case Some(x) => x
}

listValues.max
listValues.min
```